# Search controller is fetching the wrong template in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to write the controller to search for articles. But the search does not find anything and a template appears that is not specified in the views.py.

```
# views.py
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'search_view.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Article.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
        return object_list

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticlesList.as_view(), name='list_view'),
    path('<tag>/', ArticlesByTagsList.as_view(), name='articles_by_tags'),
    path('articles/<slug:slug>', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='detail_view'),
    path('articles/create/', ArticleCreate.as_view(), name='create_view'),
    path('articles/<slug:slug>/', ArticleUpdate.as_view(), name='update_view'),
    path('articles/<slug:slug>/delete/', ArticleDelete.as_view(), name='delete_view'),
    path('search/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search_view'),
]


#search_view.html
{% extends 'layout/basic.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {{ object_list }}
{% endblock %}
```

The form looks like this

```
<form action="{% url 'articles:search_view' %}" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your full urls.py? You probably have another path matching "/search/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enumerate over the objects, so:

```
{% extends 'layout/basic.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for object in object_list %}
        {{ object.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

You should also specify the `search/` path before the `<tag>/` path, since Django always takes the item that first matches, and if you write `search/` then it would first match with the `<tag>/` and thus not fire the `SearchView`.

The `urlpatterns` thus should look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
     #       ↓ first specify the search/ path
     path('search/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search_view'),
     path('<tag>/', ArticlesByTagsList.as_view(), name='articles_by_tags'),
]
```

an effect of this, is that you can not use `search` as a tag. If you should be able to visit the `articles_by_tags` with `search` as tag, you should define non-overlapping patterns, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('search/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search_view'),
     path('tag/<tag>/', ArticlesByTagsList.as_view(), name='articles_by_tags'),
]
```

Comment: I tried. But still nothing works. The search result retrieves a template related to another route. In the application I use taggit and it seems that the search is returning a template referring to the articles_by_tags route.
`urlpatterns = [
    path('<tag>/', ArticlesByTagsList.as_view(), name='articles_by_tags'),
    path('search/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search_view'),
]`

Comment: @ilsurealism: can you add the `urlpatterns` to your question. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68963390/edit) the question.

Comment: @ilsurealism: you need to specify the `search_view` first in the `urlpatterns`, since `<tag>` can also match with search.

Comment: Did. But now, instead of the search result, the error TemplateDoesNotExist at /search/ appears.

Comment: I had templates with a list of articles: articles_by_tag.html and list_view.html. But when I additionally added a template article_list.html the search engine started working correctly. I still don’t understand why it was necessary to add another template with a list and is it always necessary to do this?

Comment: @ilsurealism: normally that should not be necessary, perhaps you can edit the question with the `list_view.html`? Are you sure you restarted the server to check if it worked with the original template?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but the TemplateDoesNotExist at /search/ error appears with the Exception Value: search_view.html, articles/article_list.html.

Comment: @ilsurealism: did you pass two templates for the same `template_name`?

Comment: No. Sorry, I understand what the error is. I incorrectly specified the path to the search_view.html template (I forgot to specify the directory).